# Is there any counterpart in Android for 'hasBeenUsed' property of interstitial ad in IOS? Need to check if ad is already presented to user

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

In my IOS code I could check if ad is already presented using 'hasBeenUsed'. But in Android, I could not find any. Is there any easy solution for this?

Below is my IOS code I need something like this in Android:

```
 if ([self.interstitial isReady] && [self.interstitial hasBeenUsed] == NO) {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code: `mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()`

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

Comment: I need to check if the ad was presented to user. In IOS we have 'hasBeenUsed' property. It will be set automatically when an ad is shown. So we can avoid repetitive ads.

Comment: If you are using AdMob it will change automatically